# PHP Portal similar to java portal

Tags: php, portal

Java has couple portal open source, does PHP has similar too? or port from java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://www.opensourcecms.com, there you'll find a list of mostly PHP - MySQL based CMSes (and you can try most of them out on the site as well).